# A component is changing the uncontrolled checked state of SwitchBase to be controlled. Elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, frontend

I have a MUI checkbox:

```
<Checkbox
    checked={rowValues[row.id]}
    onChange={() => {
                       const temp = { ...rowValues, [row.id]: !rowValues[row.id] };
                       setRowValues(temp);
              }}
    inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'controlled' }}
/>
```

and there is a select all button

```
<Button
    onClick={async () => {
                            isAllSelected = !isAllSelected;
                            const tmp = await setAllValues(isAllSelected);
                            setRowValues(tmp);
                          }}
    size="small"
    variant="contained"
>
{isAllSelected ? 'Unselect All' : 'Select All'}
</Button>
```

Both of these make use of the `rowValues` whoose structure looks like this:

```
{
625fd0bc4163c339b4235286: true
627df6084067debf4de42287: true
629a481d848843b1baaf7945: true
6260feb706684d04a43da863: true
62809135dbf57c3ee8d7efd4: true
}
```

Code related to default value and initialization:

```
const [rowValues, setRowValues] = useState([]);
    let temp = [];
    async function setAllValues(value) {
        await stableSort(rows, getComparator(order, orderBy))
            .slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)
            .forEach((row) => {
                temp = { ...temp, [row.id]: value };
            });
        console.log('| temp', temp);
        return temp;
    }
    React.useEffect(() => {
        setAllValues(false).then(setRowValues);
    }, []);
```

When i click the select all button, all the values for the corresponding ID's get changed to true. Now for the checked prop in the checkbox, Im setting it to the value for the corresponding ID(either true or false). Instead i got an error:

index.js:1 Material-UI: A component is changing the uncontrolled checked state of SwitchBase to be controlled.
Elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa).
Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled SwitchBase element for the lifetime of the component.
The nature of the state is determined during the first render. It's considered controlled if the value is not `undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

That happens because your initial value is undefined/null. Use '' instead, that should solve the problem

Comment: Hi, kindly check, ive edited the post for code related to initialization, default values and suggest on the same.

Comment: @VedantShah did you make shure that the data is always defined when component is rendering. If by any reason the data is undefined, maybe because of an async call, then the checkbox initializes being uncontrolled

Answer (score 1):

i think this happened because of the inital state value, try to change initial value of all checkboxes to false instead undefined
then i think it will be Ok.

Comment: Hi, kindly check, ive edited the post for code related to initialization, default values and suggest on the same.

Answer (score 1):

For MUI `<Switch>` component I have to use `?? false` instead of `''`

```
const [notification, setNotification] = useState(user?.notification ?? false);
```

....

```
const handleChangeNotification = (event) => {
    setNotification(event.target.checked ?? false);
}
```

and in JSX part:

```
   <Switch
      checked={notification}
      onChange={handleChangeNotification}
    />
```